# How do you find the coordinates of the cursor in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I found this code to be the most helpful to other people:

```
x, y = win32api.GetCursorPos()
```

When I run this code, I get an error "NameError: name 'win32gui' is not defined on line ##".

When trying to import the module:

```
import win32gui
```

I get an error "ImportError: No module named win32gui on line ##".

I tried running:

```
pip install win32gui
```

But it doesn't seem to work. How can I use win32gui?

Comment: `win32gui` is not part of the standard library, it is a third-party library that you will need to install.

Comment: Yes indeed @juanpa.arrivillaga he needs to install `pywin32` module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`win32gui` comes as a part of the external package [PyWin32](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/). You may download this package to install this module.

Note that this is not a part of the standart library (a third party library, proceed with caution).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a third party module pyautogui, which is installed by: pip install pyautogui

Code for mouse position:

```
import pyautogui
print pyautogui.position()
```

It will return a tuple with your x, y coordinate position

Comment: Pip should be installed on your machine already since you have python but if not, download the pip package mentioned in the answer to the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windowsrun and then run this command to install pip: python get-pip.py